# How to get a path name as a parameter in JAX-RS @Path

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I want to create a REST service where the parameter is a path with a non-fixed number of terms. For example:

```
@Path("obj")
public class ObjectResource {

   @GET
   @Path(???)
   public Response getObj(@Param(???) String path) {
      ....
   }
}
```

If the request URL is like:

```
http://myhost.xyz/app/obj/var/share/www
```

The method **getObj** would get as its **path** parameter the String

```
var/share/www
```

Alternatively it would be OK to get an array (or **Collection**) with "var" "share" "www" in separate ordered elements.  (I would just do a **String.split()** on the single string anyway.)

Can this be done?

Comment: [UriInfo](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_contextobjects_uri.html) is your friend

Comment: @RomanVottner Well that was absurdly easy.  If you want to write that up as an answer I'll mark it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [PathSegment](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html).

```java
@Path("obj")
public class ObjectResource {

   @GET
   @Path("{var: \\.+}")
   public Response getObj(@PathParam("var") final PathSegment path) {
       final String value = path.getPath();
   }
}
```

Edit:   What actually works is the following:

```
@GET
@Path("obj")
public class ObjectResource {    

    @Path("{part: .*}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getObj(@PathParam("part") String pathpart) {

        // just return the path
        return Response.ok(pathpart).build();
    }
 }
```